# Binding to ObservableCollection is Being a Very Naughty Boy

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I have an WPF MVVM application that has suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason. I have version of the system that is a week older and does not have that many changes and this works fine.

**The problem is**: I have an `DataGrid` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` (OC) and the binding is fine and the `DataGrid` is populated. I can delete from the `ObservableCollection` and that delete operation is reflected in the view (the item removed from the OC, is removed from the `DataGid` [View]). However, when I add an item, the view is no longer updated the way it was. I have stepped through the old and new code together (side-by-side) and they are both doing exactly the same thing and the `ObservableCollection` is being updated in both cases. The problem is the newer system is not updating the view. **Why?**.

I have used Snoop to check the bindings and the DataContext and these are not throwing any errors and *seem* fine. I have not changed the XAML of the application from the one that work to the newer one that doesn't. I have removed most smaller changes to the new code to try and getting working with no joy, **what other avenues can I use to attempt to resolve why the binding is not working in this case?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you post code to show how you are adding items to the OC? Also, OC decleration in VM.

Comment: Well I cannot believe, that I've to tell you this. But could you please post the code, so that we can help solve your current issue? Due to the fact, that it's part of the question. Answering your second question is not that easy. But I'm eager to read the recommendations. :-)

Comment: Clearly I am not new to the site and if I thought that having the code would be of any use here I would have posted it. The truth is, the code is complex and to get across the problem using code would just take too much space. I am basically asking for other ways I can delve into the problem, not for the problem to be solved for me... This is a last resort as I have already spent a lot of time trying to track this down.

Comment: Perform a diff between your two versions of code, and go through each and every difference working from your working version to your non working version, making the changes, until it breaks. That last change is likely the culprit.

Comment: I have used ExamDiff to do this, but I skipped some modules I thought 'nah' to. i will have to go back and do this properly removing hundreds of lines. Good advice, thanks...

Comment: I had this once before and put a listener on the underlying collection view source.  I also used an aggressive 'clean.bat' file that forcefully deleted each and every artefact in the solution space.

Comment: @GarryVass that really does sound aggressive... I like it. I am going for the old Diff and Check approach. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of questions are very hard, maybe even impossible to answer. I've been in a similar situation where a project that used to work suddenly stopped working without my intervention... or so I thought. In reality, I had made a small change that I had forgotten about in an area unrelated to the area where the problem showed itself.

For my sanity, I can only assume that you have done the same, because if previously working programs really stop working on their own, then we'd all have big problems. Unfortunately, there's really not much help that anyone can give you... you're going to have to deconstruct your view and view model (or copies of them) bit by bit until you come across something that doesn't look right. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: "...because if previously working programs really stop working on their own, then we'd all have big problems". Also, job security for life!

Comment: I feared this! To be honest, I am having one of the worst development weeks of my life. I am in a hole and it's deep and dark. Deconstruction is never something I wanted to start but, it does look like I may as well... Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Flater... don't worry my friend... all developers make enough mistakes to keep us all in work anyway. And Killercam, the only help I can give you really is to suggest that you take a copy of your view/view model before you hack them to pieces. Good luck

Comment: Cheers mate. As always, you time is appreciated...